# yii2 redirect in init does it work or not?

Tags: redirect, yii2, init

```
class TestController extends Controller {
    function init() {
       if(!(strtolower(yii::$app->requestedRoute) == "account/login" || empty(yii::$app->requestedRoute)))
       {
           if (false===$this->isLogin()) {

               return $this->redirect('/login');   //it works, will redirect

           }
       } else {
           if($this->isLogin()) {
               return $this->redirect('/purchaser/manifest');   //not work, won't redirect
                //echo $this->redirect('/purchaser/manifest');    //work


           }
       }
   }
}
```

I had overriden Controller. When I tried to do filter, I found this problem. I'm confused, any help?

Answer (score 7):

From Yii2 docs:

> In case the action should not run, the request should be handled
>   inside of the `beforeAction` code by either providing the necessary
>   output or redirecting the request. Otherwise the response will be
>   empty.

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
         return false;
    }
    // your custom code here
    //Eg
    if(something){
         $this->redirect('/login');
         return false; //not run the action
    }

    return true; // continue to run action
}
```

Yii2 not care about return value of `init()` function. Applications will still continue to run action.
About `redirect()` function, It will not work until application completed (`beforeAction` return false or an action return). So when you call `redirect()` in `init()` function nothing happens.
But `return $this->redirect('/login');` It works. Why? Because in this case, application redirect after run your action.
you can try, even write `$this->redirect('/login');` It still works.

Comment: thanks your answer, but i had to use "echo $this->redirect('/purchaser/manifest')". At least I knew the reason.